# Upload images or photos on Facebook using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How i can upload image or photo on Facebook Wall using `Outh_key` or `access token` without login using PHP?

Please help me & thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some various ways to upload photos using the Graph API. The examples assume you've instantiated the $facebook object and have a valid session.

**1 - Default Application Album of Current User**

This example will upload the photo to your default application album of the current user. If the album does not yet exist it will be created.

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

**2 - Target Album**

This example will upload the photo to a specific album.

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

you can also specify this in the Facebook constructor:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => 'ID', 'secret' => 'SECRET', 'fileUpload' => true, 'cookie' => true));
```

---

**Another Option**

```
//upload photo
$file= '/path/filename.jpg';
$args = array(
   'message' => 'Photo from application',
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//returns the photo id
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

Comment: Thanks Adeel Mughal I used this Graph API in web service,but it takes too much for uploading image.

Comment: Increase your upvote count to get more reputation & so some sportsmanship.